# How can we incorporating uncertainty about our data into Bayesian inference?

Tags: bayesian, inference, binomial-distribution, uncertainty

I want to use a Bayesian approach to estimate the parameter $\theta$ of a binomial distribution $\textsf{Binomial}(\theta,n)$ with the number of Bernoulli experiments $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ being known and fixed to $n$.

In the textbook example, the binomial likelihood only takes the sum of positive vs. negative outcomes of $x_i$ into account:
\begin{equation}
f(x|\theta) = \theta^{\sum x_i} (1-\theta)^{n-\sum x_i}
\end{equation}

Together with a uniform prior $f(\theta)=\textsf{Uniform}(0,1)$, the posterior becomes the Beta distribution
\begin{equation}
f(\theta|s) = \textsf{Beta}(\theta|s+1,n-s+1) . 
\end{equation}
, where $s=\sum x_i$. Unfortunately, $x_i$ is not directly observable. Instead, we are given $\pi_i$ as features to e.g. a neural network, which then provides a probabilistic mapping $f(x_i|\pi_i)$. This probability represents uncertainty about the true, latent value $x_i$.

How can we incorporate this uncertainty about the data into the estimate? E.g. if $f(x_i|\pi_i)=0.51\ \forall\ 0\leq\ i<n$, we would expect the MAP estimate of $\theta$ to be a lot further off from $1$ than if $f(x_i|\pi_i)=0.91$ throughout.

Comment: Is the input directly observable?

Comment: @AccidentalStatistician Adjusted the problem statement to clarify this: $x_i$ is not directly observable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distribution for $\theta$ conditional on $s$ (and $n$) is
\begin{equation}
p(\theta|s) = \textsf{Beta}(\theta|s+1,n-s+1) . 
\end{equation}
The problem is that we don't observe $s$.

Instead we are given $\pi = (\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_n)$, where
\begin{equation}
p(x_i|\pi_i) = \textsf{Bernoulli}(x_i|\pi_i)  
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
p(x|\pi) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i|\pi_i) .
\end{equation}
We can compute $p(s|\pi)$ from $p(x|\pi)$ and then
\begin{equation}
p(\theta|\pi) = \sum_{s=0}^n p(\theta|s)\,p(s|\pi) ,
\end{equation}
which is a mixture of beta distributions.

The problem now is that $p(s|\pi)$ is the Poisson-binomial distribution which is difficult to compute analytically unless $n$ is quite small. One solution is to use simulation to approximate the distribution. In particular, let
\begin{equation}
p(\theta|\pi) \approx \frac{1}{R} \sum_{r=1}^R p(\theta|s^{(r)}) ,
\end{equation}
where $s^{(r)} \sim p(s|\pi)$.

Let me provide more detail. Let
\begin{equation}
s^{(r)} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{(r)} ,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
x_i^{(r)} \sim p(x_i|\pi_i) .
\end{equation}
Now define the approximate mixture weights:
\begin{equation}
\hat w_j = \frac{1}{R}\sum_{r=1}^R 1(s^{(r)} = j) ,
\end{equation}
where the indicator function is
\begin{equation}
1(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{$x$ is true} \\
0 & \text{$x$ is false}
\end{cases} .
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
p(\theta|\pi) \approx \sum_{j=0}^n \hat w_j\,p(\theta|s=j) . 
\end{equation}
You will need to experiment to see how large $R$ needs to be so that you get a sufficiently accurate answer. Depending on $n$ and $\pi$, you might need $R = 10^5$ or more.

Comment: Thanks for the second approach, which makes a lot of sense. I just need some clarification on the approximation: do I assume correctly that you suggest to sample $R$-times $s$ from $p(s|\pi)$? If so, how do I calculate an individual sample for $s \in [0,n]$ with $n \approx 3000?$

Comment: I updated my original question below, such that it notationally conforms with your proposed solution (choice of parameter), and already states the form of the vanilla Beta distribution, making it unecessary for you to add this detail.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the update @mef, perfectly understandable now. Will check it out.